Section headings overflow the bottom of the page and don't start on the next page automatically
Using TexStudio to write a document and each chapter seems to be only confined to 1 page worth of sections. The sections just 'go off the bottom of the page'. This is my preamble, I have no idea what I'm actually using though.

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper, hidelinks]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%ensure the lists are not separated
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep}

%Setting up the margins
\usepackage[a4paper, 
            left = 0.9in,
            right = 0.9in,
            top = 1in, 
            bottom = 1in, 
            footskip = 0.5in]{geometry}
            
%To eliminate the word 'Chapter' from chapters
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Large}

%Spacing between each paragraph
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\raggedbottom

\begin{document}
\chapter{}
\section{}
...
\end{document}

I've tried searching and got the suggestion that I manually input a new page or page break where appropriate to achieve the page flow but I feel there is probably a much easier way to implement this.

Do you get page breaks if you actually add text in your sections? Please make a [mre]

If I add text to a section it moves to the next page however, the section on the first page still flows down into the footer.

Intro
From the first glance at the Latex documentation (1) seems that when you define sections using the \section{} command without any accompanying text, the document does not automatically insert page breaks between sections. This behavior is because LaTeX's default mechanism does not enforce page breaks for sections unless there is enough content to push the text to the next page.
From the documentation (1), the handling of section commands is covered in the section "7.2 Chapters and Sections".
Answer
If you add text to your section, you will see that the section themselves will fulfil the conditions you expect, i.e. they will go on the new page.
If you wish to write nothing, I recommend using \null immediately after section:
\section{..}
\null

Latex takes the meaning of \null to mean ‘take no text as text’, so all that would follow if you added text (which helps in proper pagination).
You could write your own command in the preamble (before \begin{document}) if you feel lazy:
\newcommand{\mysection}[1]{
\section{#1}
\null}

Therefore just write:
\mysection{Section 1}

\mysection{Section 2}

and so on.
The documentation of all classes is available here: (2)
